# Restkit object mapping with multiple root objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, restkit

I have a web service that returns a JSON in the following format:

```
{
"client": {
         "firstName": "Aaron"
         },
"error": {
         "code":""
         }
}
```

And I am having setting up the mapping in restkit. I keep getting the following error:

`Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''" UserInfo=0x5961f0 {=RKObjectMapperKeyPath, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''}`

Here is how I am setting up the mappings:

```
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:[Client objectMapping] forKeyPath:@"client"];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:[ErrorObject objectMapping] forKeyPath:@"error"];
```

Client Mapping:

```
+(RKObjectMapping*) objectMapping {
   RKObjectMapping* responseObjectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Client class]];
   [responseObjectMapping setRootKeyPath:@"client"];
   [responseObjectMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
    @"firstName", @"firstName",
    nil];
   return responseObjectMapping;
}
```

Error Mapping:

```
+(RKObjectMapping*) objectMapping {
   RKObjectMapping* responseObjectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ErrorObject class]];
   [responseObjectMapping setRootKeyPath:@"error"];
   [responseObjectMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
    @"code", @"code",
    nil];
   return responseObjectMapping;
}
```

And calling the service like this:

```
//Send initial load request
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[@"/getdetails" stringByAppendingQueryParameters:params] usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.delegate = self;
    loader.userData = INITIAL_LOAD_REQUEST;
}];
```

---

**EDIT:**

I fixed my problem by following advice below and also moving my mapping from the init method to setting it in the object loader block like this:

```
    //Send initial load request
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[@"/getdetails" stringByAppendingQueryParameters:params] usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.delegate = self;

    //set mapping explicitly
    RKObjectMappingProvider *provider = [[RKObjectMappingProvider alloc] init];
    [provider setMapping:[Clien objectMapping] forKeyPath:@"client"];
    [provider setMapping:[ErrorObject objectMapping] forKeyPath:@"error"];
    [loader setMappingProvider:provider];

    loader.userData = INITIAL_LOAD_REQUEST;
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the lines

```
[responseObjectMapping setRootKeyPath:@"client"];
```

and

```
[responseObjectMapping setRootKeyPath:@"error"];
```

Comment: Giving me the same error : `Request didFailLoadWithError: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''" UserInfo=0x5a56e0 {=RKObjectMapperKeyPath, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''}`

Comment: Fixed it, your comment lead me on the right track, and I moved my mappings from the init method to setting them explicitly for the loader. Edited my question to show this. Thanks.